# jQuery adding option to select box with selected arbitrate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a option to a existing select element.

Below code works without any issue

```
$('#selectStory').append($('<option>', {
    value: 1,
    text: 'Red'
}));
```

Only issue is that i cant make it selected.

Can someone tell me how to do this.

Comment: I can't see any problem in it. See https://jsfiddle.net/ausejzbv/

Comment: @Mohammad OP wants to set the appended option to be selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#selectStory').append($('<option>', {
  value: 1,
  text: 'Red',
  selected: 'selected'
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='selectStory'>
  <option></option>
</select>
```

Add `selected`